# What is wrong with the way I called a widget?

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to put a PHP page (footer.php) in widget (text) using the following code

**CODE PHP:**

```
 <div class="col-md-4"><?php the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Text' ); ?> </div>
```

Unfortunately not show anything ... not an error occurs, you tell me please if properly how I tried to do this?

There are better ways?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you drop widget in sidebar in wordpress admin ?

Comment: yes,in footer sidebar

Comment: You can't simply put widget directly into the footer.php. you have to create wp-widget class and register your custom widget to WordPress. Than it will appear in the back end of WordPress widget page. There you have to select it to apply on your footer widget. Or else after creating the widget you can simple call the widget class on dynamic sidebar to get your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You've called the text widget but did not specified what to display in that text widget.

You also need to pass the second argument in `the_widget` function.
e.g.

```
the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Text', array(
       'title' => 'My text widget', 
       'text' => 'This is text widget without sidebar')
 );
```

See [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget#Text_widget)

Answer (score -1):

Check this tutorial. You have to create a custom widget class which will extends the WP_Widget class.

[Coding and Registering Your WordPress Widget](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/coding-and-registering-your-wordpress-widget--cms-22404)

Also register sidebar position for dropping some widgets from the wp-admin panel.
[Register Sidebar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar)

Thanks